# Call method in UITableViewController from custom UITableViewController in Xamarin

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios, custom-cell

In UITableViewController I have a method that update bottom toolbar that shows total price.

```
        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            var cell = (CartCell)tableView.DequeueReusableCell(CellIdentifier, indexPath);
            if (cell == null)
            {
                cell = new CartCell(this.Handle);
            }
            cell.UpdateCartCell(tableItems[indexPath.Row]);
            return cell;
        }
```

In  UITableViewCell I have a UIStepper. I can't figure out, how I can call method in  UITableViewController, when stepper was pressed, so i will be able to update my bottom toolbar text.

```
partial class CartCell : UITableViewCell
{
    int quantity;
    float cartItemTotal;

    public CartCell(IntPtr handle)
        : base(handle)
    {
    }

    public void UpdateCartCell(CartItem cartItem)
    {
        quantity = cartItem.Quantity;
        cartItemTotal = cartItem.thisTotal;

        productName.Text = cartItem.Name;
        productDescription.Text = cartItem.Description;
        productQuantyty.Text = quantity.ToString();
        productPrice.Text = cartItem.Price;
        stepper.Value = quantity;
        stepper.MinimumValue = 1;
        stepper.ValueChanged += (o, s) =>
        {
            double value = stepper.Value;

            #region **** QTY Remove****
            if (value < quantity)
            { ... }
            #endregion

            #region **** QTY Add****
            if (value > quantity)
            { ... }
            #endregion
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CartCell I've added                 NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.PostNotificationName("ValueDidChanged", this);

```
public void UpdateCartCell(CartItem cartItem)
{
     stepper.ValueChanged += (o, s) =>
    {
        double value = stepper.Value;

        #region **** QTY Remove****
        if (value < quantity)
        { ... }
        #endregion

        #region **** QTY Add****
        if (value > quantity)
        { ... }
        #endregion
        NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.PostNotificationName("ValueDidChanged", this);
    };
}
```

And in UITableViewController I am listening for notification:

```
     observer = NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver((NSString)"ValueDidChanged", UpdateSettings);
```

And calling method to update total:

```
    void UpdateSettings(NSNotification obj)
    {
        UpdateTotal();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar case where I needed such a functionality. What I did was to add an event to the cell and consume it in my `UITableViewSource` which has a reference to the controller.

Comment: Thank you, yes that is good way of solving this problem, but finally i figure out and implement notifications. In case if you use notifications, you need less code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain an iOS feel, you would use the iOS Delegate pattern (see the  section on [Events, Delegates and Protocols](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/delegates,_protocols,_and_events/) on the Xamarin site).

Basically, you would declare a protocol (an Interface in C# parlance) to notify the observing class (in your case the UITableViewController instance) e.g.

```
public interface CartCellStepperDelegate
{
    void cartCellValueChanged(int value);
}
```

A weak reference to the delegate should be maintained in your observing class which the instance of CartCell can communicate with.

It would be as simple as implementing the interface in the UITableViewController instance and acting accordingly once actioned. This is sort of analagous to a C# event (which, by the way, is another option that you could use where you define an event in the CartCell class and bind it to the touch event on the Stepper).